# With an if statement how do I get numbers ending in 1?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I want to display the numbers which ends with one.

Example: if (1,3,4,11,15,21) is the set of numbers, I want to  display (1,11,21). Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: with the help of if statement want  to display 1,11,21 in the above set of number

Comment: iterate through your list objects, in the if block convert your items to string and check for ends with "1".

Comment: @mack what kind of set is it? how do you save the items? `List<int>` ? or array: `int[]` ?

Answer (score 2):

**if** you really want to diplay them with the help of if statements
try this:

```
// example array with numbers
int[] setOfNumbers = new int[10]{1,22,21,34,41,51,111,121,99,10001};

// the for-loop would also work with a List
foreach (int item in setOfNumbers)
{ 
    // chose what ever method to display. In a Console application usualy this:
    if(item % 10 == 1)  // if the rest of a whole number division is 1 like 21/10 = 2 rest 1
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

otherwise Linq is quite powerfull:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", setOfNumbers.Where<int>(x=>x % 10 == 1).ToList()));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (int value in numbers) {
    if (value.ToString().EndsWith("1")) {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use LinQ:

```
    List<int> a = new List<int>() {1,3,4,11,15,21};
    var b = a.Where(i => i.ToString().Contains("1")).ToList();
```

Comment: This will capture not only numbers that end with 1 but every that contains 1 like 11111119